# jQuery ajax handling of 204 No Content

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling, http-status-code-204

I am writing an jQuery `ajax` call to a RESTful server, for which the response to a valid PUT request is an HTTP 204 No Content. The response has a `Content Type` header of `application/text` but there is no content body. Because of this, it appears that the `ajax` call threats this as an error, and so the `error` function is called instead of `done`.

Is there a way to override this behaviour, and execute `done` for a 204 response regardless of the content body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to fix the problem by adding a filter to the [ajax request settings](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

```
dataFilter: function(data,type) {
    return data || "{}"
}
```

This ensures that `JSON.parse` never receives empty content when it is called within ajax on the response content.

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to make a call for `statusCode` in `ajax`. And make a runner code in specific `statusCode`.

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var settings = {
            "URL": "<your link>",
            "method": "POST",
            "timeout": 0,
            "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
        "data": JSON.stringify({
            "email": email,
            "user_name": user_name,
        }),
        "statusCode": {
            200: function (data) {
                console.log("Request completed 200");
                resolve(data || {statusCode: 200});
            }, 
            201: function (data) {
                console.log("Request completed 201");
                resolve(data || {statusCode: 201});
            },
            204: function (data) {
                console.log("Request completed 204");
                resolve(data || { statusCode: 204});
            }
        }
    };

    $.ajax(settings)
});
```